# How to look for annotations in eclipse java search

Tags: java, eclipse, search

I would like to find **all annotations** used in project (annotatons that are **assigned to type, field or method**). I have hoped that **java search** would help me with it, but I was not able to make that work.

*P.S. I cannot just search for @, because its also used in javadocs.*

*P.S. 2. I do not know all annotations that are used in project, so I cannot search for it by name.*

Answer (score 6):

Try: CTRL-H -> File Search, check Case Sensitive and Regular expression, and input:

- @[A-Z] for Containing text
- *.java for File name patterns
- maybe restrict scope to selected resources (and select your project before)

This way you'll find all the occurences of type "@ followed by any uppercase character". Normally this should leave out the javadocs and leave you with actual annotation occurances.